# Angular UI-Grid infinite scroll/pagination not keeping previous data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The issue I'm running into is that when my scroll bar reaches near the bottom, it makes the call for the next 100 records in the result set, however, it replaces the previous 100 records with the new 100. Am I missing something with infinite scroll. Here is my controller logic

```
'use strict';

var first = angular.module('TqimApp');
first.controller('NewGridCtrl',  ['$scope', '$http', 'NewGridService', '$timeout', '$modal', '$interval', '$location', 'uiGridConstants', '$filter', '$rootScope',
function($scope, $http, NewGridService, $timeout, $modal, $interval, $location, uiGridConstants, $filter, $rootScope) {
$( "div[id^='nvtooltip']" ).css( "display" , "none");

var id, af;
$scope.headers = [];
$scope.reportQuery = {};
$scope.gridOptions = {};
$scope.pageNumber=0;
$scope.recordNumber=0;
$scope.totalItemsSize=0;
$scope.modeValue = true;
$scope.orderByColumn=null;
$scope.defaultOrderByColumn=null;
var paginationOptions = { pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 25, sort: null };
var params = [];
var whereColumn=[];
$scope.columnName=null;
$scope.columnValue=null;
$scope.gridApi=null;

var words = tokenize( location.href,  '?'); //20160221 moved, changed path to location.href
var words = splitTheSecond( words,  '&'); //20160221 moved

angular.forEach(words, function(word, idx) { //20160221 moved
    var subw = tokenize( word,  '=');
    params[subw[0]]=subw[1];
});

function tokenize( str, token ){
    if( str == null ) return null;
    var words = str.split( token );
    if( words==null || words.length<2 ) {
          console.log( "tokenize error on parsing path " + str );
          return null;
    }
    return words;
};

function splitTheSecond( arrStr, token){
    if( !$.isArray(arrStr) ) return null;
    return tokenize(arrStr[1], token);
};

$scope.grid = {
    'cd': params['cd'],
    'catCd': params['catCd'],
    'id': params['id'],
    'af': params['af'],
    'isPaged': true,
    'recordNumber': 0,
    'pageSize': 100, //20160221 added
    'pd': params['pd'],                              /* production date*/
    'pg': $scope.pageNumber,                         /* page number */
    'ps': paginationOptions.pageSize,                /* page size */
    'oc': $scope.columnName,                         /* order column name */
    'ov': $scope.columnValue,                        /* order column value */
    'order': paginationOptions.sort,                 /* ASCending or DEScending */
    'rv': params['rv'],                               /* result value*/
    's1': params['s1'],                               /* string1*/
    's2': params['s2'],                               /* string2*/
    's3': params['s3'],                               /* string3*/
    's4': params['s4'],                               /* string4*/
    's5': params['s5'],                               /* string5*/
    'month' : params['month']                         /*month*/
};

if( params.filterIds != undefined ) {
    $scope.grid.filterIds = decodeURIComponent( params.filterIds );
}
if( params.qp != undefined ) {
    var qp = decodeURIComponent( params.qp );
    $scope.grid.qp = JSON.parse(qp);
}

$scope.highlightFilteredHeader = function( row, rowRenderIndex, col, colRenderIndex ) {
    if( col.filters[0].term ){
        return 'header-filtered';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
     //columnDefs: $scope.headers,
     enablePaginationControls: true,
     enableFiltering: true,
     enableSorting: true,
     useExternalSorting: true,
     visible: true,
     infiniteScrollDown: true,
     infiniteScrollUp: true,
     exporterMenuCsv: true,
     exporterMenuPdf: false,
     enableGridMenu: true,
};

NewGridService.getHeaders($scope.grid.catCd).then(
          function(result)  {
                var returnArray = [];                   
                for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ){
                      returnArray.push({field: result[i].key, displayName: result[i].name, 
                      enableFiltering: true,  headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader, 
                      filter: { term: "", }});
                }                                         
                $scope.defaultOrderByColumn = $scope.grid.catCd == 'CMP_GRD'? 'complaint_result_id' : 'test_result_id';
                $scope.headers = returnArray;
                $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = $scope.headers;
         },
         function(error){
             console.error(error);
});

var getPage = function(whereColumn) {
    console.log('getPage');

    $scope.reportQuery.whereColumn = whereColumn;
    $scope.reportQuery.fromIndex = $scope.pageNumber;
    $scope.reportQuery.toIndex = paginationOptions.pageSize;
    $scope.reportQuery.orderByColumn = $scope.sortColumnName;
    $scope.grid.recordNumber = $scope.grid.recordNumber + $scope.grid.pageSize;

    getGridData();
    console.log('Grid Size: '+$scope.grid.recordNumber);
};

$scope.getDataDown = function() {
    if($scope.modeValue) {
        $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded().then(function() {
            getPage(whereColumn);
        }).then(function() {
            }
        );
    }
};

$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
           console.log('onRegisterApi');
           $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

           $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged($scope, function(grid,  sortColumns) {
                    console.log('sort changed!');
                    console.log(sortColumns);

                    //20160221 added variable resets
                    $scope.grid.totalRecordCount = 0;
                    $scope.grid.recordNumber = 0;

                    //20160221 added block of code to refresh grid after sort
                    var sortClmnList = [];
                    if(sortColumns.length == 0) {
                        sortClmnList.push($scope.defaultOrderByColumn+" ASC");
                    } else {
                        angular.forEach(sortColumns,  function(sCriteria) {
                            sortClmnList.push(sCriteria.name+" "+sCriteria.sort.direction);
                        });
                    }
                    $scope.grid.sortCriteria = sortClmnList;

                    getGridData();
          });

          $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope,  function() { //20160221 added
                console.log('filter changed!');

                //20160221 added block of code to refresh grid after filter
                var whereColumn = [];
                angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs,  function(obj) {
                    if(obj.visible) {
                        $scope.column.push(obj.name);
                    }
                    if(obj.filter.term!="" && obj.filter.term!=null) {
                        whereColumn.push(obj.name+","+obj.filter.term);
                    }
                });

                $scope.grid.whereColumn = whereColumn;
                $scope.totalItemsSize = $scope.gridOptions.data.length;
                console.log('$scope.grid.whereColumn='+whereColumn);
                getGridData();

        });
        gridApi.infiniteScroll.on.needLoadMoreData($scope, $scope.getDataDown);
};

function formatDates(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        if(data[i].production_Date != null) {
            var currentValue = data[i].production_Date;
            var currentDate = new Date(parseInt(currentValue));
            var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = currentDate.getDate();
            if( day < 10 ) {
                day = '0'+ day;
            }
            var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
            var date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            data[i].production_date = date;
         }
    }        
};

function getGridData() { 
    NewGridService.getGridData($scope.grid).then(
    function(data){console.log(data);
        formatDates(data);
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        $scope.totalItemsSize = $scope.totalItemsSize + $scope.gridOptions.data.length;
        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.gridOptions.data.concat($scope.gridOptions.data);
    },
    function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
 }
 getGridData();

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your issue.

function getGridData() { 
... 
$scope.gridOptions.data = data; // replacing data 
... 
$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.gridOptions.data.concat($scope.gridOptions.data);
... 
}

see line with comment: 
so your previous data will be overwritten before you concat the old with new data.

greets Christian